# ClosedRange<Int>.Index to Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, indexing, range, variable-types

My code:

```
let range = 30...200 //ranges may have different bounds
let index = range.firstIndex(of: 55)
```

The problem is `index` has type `ClosedRange<Int>.Index` and it is unclear how to convert it to `Int` now for further usage.

I understand that it is simplier to convert range to array and look for int index in it but they somehow should allow to use `ClosedRange<Int>.Index` by itself

Note: there are may be similar questions but all of them about how to convert `ClosedRange<Int>` to an array, not index conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ClosedRange<Bound>.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/index) is literally just an enum that doesn't tell you anything useful.

```
enum Index {
    case inRange(Bound)
    case pastEnd
}
```

Something as simple as this is enough to correctly implement the index-related methods that `Collection` and other protocols require.

`firstIndex(of: 55)` would return `inRange(55)` if 55 is in the range, and `pastEnd` otherwise.

Also note that `firstIndex` ([and other `Collection` methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/collection-implementations)) is only available when `Bound` conforms to `Stridable` and the `Stride` conforms to `SignedInteger`. After all, it doesn't make sense to treat a `ClosedRange<Double>` or a `ClosedRange<String>` as a `Collection`.

So the only ranges where an operation like `firstIndex(of: 55)` makes sense, is when `Bound: Stridable, Bound.Stride: SignedInteger`. You can find out the "numeric" index of an element in such a range by using [`distance(to: lowerBound)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int64/distance(to:)), which is a method on `Stridable`.

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound: Strideable, Bound.Stride: SignedInteger {
    func numericIndex(of element: Bound) -> Bound.Stride? {
        if contains(element) {
            return element.distance(to: lowerBound)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

For `ClosedRange<Int>`, this is basically subtraction. The index of 55 in 30...200 is simply 55 - 30 = 25.